# How to validate Radio Button in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: javascript, html

If I check one day, no problem. I will leave one day. But when i check more day, i want to appear "date" From.... to....

```
<label class="radio-inline">
 <input type="radio" name="optradio">One Day</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
 <input type="radio"name="optradio">More Day</label>
```

Comment: Do you have some javascript or..? I mean, have you tried to do something already or is this all you have attempted? (yet)

Comment: I m confusing with code. I clear all. :D I can't twists

Comment: Do you have a clear idea of what you have to do? You're looking quite confused. In your case, you should, in my hopinion, add an hidden div containing the "date from" and "date to" inputs, listen to the change radio event on optradio and give a **value** property to the radio buttons. If the value correspond to the more day input, then show the dates.

Answer (score 0):

Add value attributes to your radio buttons so you can distinguish which is selected.

```
<label class="radio-inline">
<input type="radio" name="optradio" value="one">One Day</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
<input type="radio"name="optradio" value="more">More Day</label>
```

onclick you will get the value of the selected radio and compare if its == 'more' if true show date picker

```
$("input:radio[name=optradio]").click(function() {
    var day = this.val();

    if (day == 'more') {
        $(".dateDiv").show();
    }
})
```